# How to change the constructor of a class

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have a class like below. The idea is is to initialize and return object of B2 but keeping the identity of both constructors similar. I dont know if this is posible in javascript and what way to do it

```
function B(privateArgs) { /* B1 Visible constructor only for encapsulation*/

    function B(args) {   /* class B2 for implementation */
    }

    var construct = new B(privateArgs);
    /* inits B2 */

    /*Idea is to make (B2Instance instanceof B1Instance) === TRUE via prototype */
    /* tried construct.prototype.constructor = this.prototype.constructor */

    B.prototype.constructor = this.prototype.constructor;
    return construct;
}


var a = new B();
/* inits new B1 but returns instanceof B2 */

console.log(a instanceof B); //false
```

I want to make the outer constructor B1 pass the instanceof test when tested against B2's Object. Because this is how we intend the class to be.

Comment: What problem are you *actually* trying to solve here? [This may help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/hasInstance), but it's not totally clear what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @JaredSmith please see additional information

Comment: That's not additional information. I know you *want* it to work that way, but doesn't explain *why*. At any rate, the only way to override `instanceof` is explained in the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```js
function outer(privateArgs) {

    function inner(args) {
    }

    inner.prototype = outer.prototype;
    var newObj = new inner(privateArgs);

    return newObj;
}

var a = new outer();
console.log(a instanceof outer); // true
```

`X instanceof Y` checks if `X.__proto__` is equal to `Y.prototype`, to make it work as you want, you have to give `inner` the prototype of `outer`, so that when you do `newObj = new inner`, `newObj.__proto__` will be set to `outer.prototype`.

Comment: Thanks that does it. But the Idea is to maintain same Identifier for Inner and outer constructor